# InvalidDefinitionException Page in integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, integration-testing, feign

I have an endpoint that returns a `Page<MyDto>`. Everything works fine, but in the integration test i receive:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Page]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
feign.codec.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Page]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I saw solution to add a wrapper for `PageImpl`, but i don't want to have create a wrapper just to be able to test the code. Is there any other simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration to your project:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignDecodeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Module pageJacksonModule() {
        return new PageJacksonModule();
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/205 for additional details.